# Docker taking all space 100%

Tags: docker

My VM where I installed docker is full, so the docker daemon stopped. Now I saw a lot of solutions on how to fix it, but the problem is all of them requiring that the docker daemon is running (`docker system prune`). But when I want to start the docker daemon, it can't and this message appears:

`Error starting daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under /var/lib/docker: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device`

Is there another way to clear the space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. One of my docker container produces 9GB of logs. You can just clear those logs manually.

1. Sort the `/var/lib/docker/containers` directory to show which container directories have the largest log files:

`du -d1 -h /var/lib/docker/containers | sort -h`

2. Clear the contents of a log file

`cat /dev/null > /var/lib/docker/containers/container_id/container_log_name`

Source: https://success.docker.com/article/no-space-left-on-device-error

Comment: Sounds like you need log rotation in that container.