# docker: no space available on tmp

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-in-docker

I'm using `docker-dind` inside my `openshift`.

I'm running against an issue related with `no enought disk space`. It means that docker is getting me:

> Error starting daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under /var/lib/docker: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device

After that I've check this disk space, and I've increased the requested space for my volume to 150GiB.

I've got the free space available again on `/var/lib/docker` using `df` and it's getting that:

```
Filesystem                           Size      Used       Available  Used% Mounted on
10.49.160.20:vol_54e09e45168fdd5c... 149.9G    100.0G     49.9G      67%   /var/lib/docker
```

As you can see there's enoguh disk space now.

Any ideas? Remember that I'm not able to run any `docker` command since docker daemon is not started.

Also, I've tested where disk space is allocated. I've seen that `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir` conains a bunch of directories:

```
$ ls /var/lib/docker/vfs/dir | wc -l
653
$ du -hs *
72.6M   0077b9a043252d5db88fe8abe13af933fd0ac915b9d5af4d4102b1cfc652d40d
72.6M   0077b9a043252d5db88fe8abe13af933fd0ac915b9d5af4d4102b1cfc652d40d-init
209.2M  0161adde630e2a544e130f73cfda10cd80c8c7e5cdd9668bc22faaff3da6076a
210.3M  0161adde630e2a544e130f73cfda10cd80c8c7e5cdd9668bc22faaff3da6076a-init
....
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you getting the disk space error even after increasing the disk space?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the issue.

Comment: Are there also any permission-related errors? Is the container running as `privileged`? See also [scc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#security-context-constraints)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker taking all space 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624581/docker-taking-all-space-100)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on docker for Mac.

I solved increasing the space in preferences->resources->"Disk image size" (for me, accessing to preferences is available if I don't close the error popup).

Answer (score 1):

Try freeing up some space by removing dangling images and volumes.
To remove dangling images

`docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker rmi`

for volumes

`docker volume ls -q -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker volume rm`